# I still need help on finishing my trench traversal program to pass all tests but am still at a standstill where it says a variable is not an iterable

Tags: javascript, graph, typeerror, nodes, iterable

This problem has still been nagging at me for weeks, and I've made no further progress. I've got previous code passing tests, and here's that which is still giving me trouble.

```
// Function to traverse trenches
function trenchTraversal(node, matrix, visited) {

    // Get coordinates of node passed in
    const [row, col] = node;

    // Log visited set
    console.log(`Visited Set: ${visited}`);

    // If node depth less than -5, return false
    if (matrix[row][col] >= -5) return false;

    // Set stack equal to node passed in
    const stack = [node];

    // Add node passed in to visited set
    visited.add(node.toString());

    // Path array
    const pathArr = [];

    // While the stack has length
    while (stack.length) {

        // Get current node from stack
        const current = stack.pop();

        // Push current node to path array
        pathArr.push(current);

        // Set current coordinates to the current node
        const [currentRow, currentCol] = current;

        // Get current node value from matrix
        const currentNode = matrix[currentRow][currentCol];

        // Find neighbors of current node
        const neighbors = findNeighbors(current, matrix);

        const neighborCoords = [];

        neighbors.forEach(neighbor => {

            neighborCoords.push([neighbor[0], neighbor[1]].toString());

        });

        // Loop through neighbors
        neighborCoords.forEach(neighborCoord => {

            // If the visited note doesn't have neighbor coordinates
            if (!visited.has(neighborCoord)) {

                // Push the neighbor onto the stack
                stack.push(neighbors[neighborCoord]);

                // Add neighbor coordinates to visisted set
                visited.add(neighborCoord.toString());

            };

            // Check if trench is T-shaped
            if (visited.has(neighborCoord[0] - 1 && neighborCoord[1] - 1)) return false;

        });

        // If the path is three or more nodes long, return true
        if (pathArr.length >= 3) return true;

    };

    // Return false
    return false;

};

// Function to identify trenches
function identifyTrench(trenchMatrix) {

    // Create set to hold visited coordinates
    const visited = new Set();

    // Loop for rows
    for (let i = 0; i < trenchMatrix.length; i++) {

        // Inner loop for columns
        for (let j = 0; j < trenchMatrix[0].length; j++) {

            // If the coordinate is deeper than -5
            if (trenchMatrix[i][j] < -5) {

                // If a valid trench exists, return true
                if (trenchTraversal([i, j], trenchMatrix, visited)) return true;

                // Else return false
                else return false;

            };

        };

    };

    // Return false if no valid trenches are found
    return false;

};
```

And I get this error.

```
TypeError: current is not iterable
```

I remember not getting this error before when I was last working on the code. I would appreciate any help in getting this problem completely resolved.